# How to add Action for Static TableView Cell tap?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

how can i respond to cell taps in static tableview? Is there a way to link it with code? I know that i can use a dynamic one but isn't it possible with a static one?

`didSelectRowAt` doesn't get called
[image]

Code for Selecting not working

```swift
class SettingsVC: UITableViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - View lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("SELECTED") // not get called
    }
}
```

Comment: Table views can only be set to "static" if they are embedded in a `UITableViewController`. So, if you can't make a "static" tableView as a subview of your `UIViewController`. You *can* use a static table view (with its controller) as a Child view controller. Handling cell taps will be done as usual by implementing `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: it is a UITableViewController but it doesn't respond to `didSelectRowAt` @DonMag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Change SettingsVC to be a subclass of `UITableViewController`.
2. Make SettingsVC the delegate of your table view, since `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is a method of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: didSelectRowAt doesn't get called. I conformed to the delegate

Comment: Hard to tell because you're not showing where you declared `didSelectRowAt`, and how you set the table's delegate.

Comment: Check question again please @GregdeJ

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a Static table in a `UIContainerView`.

Here is the Storyboard setup:

[image]

and how it looks at run-time:

[image]

When you use a `UIContainerView` it creates an **embed** segue... and that will trigger a `prepare` call where you can set the tableView's delegate to self (if desired).

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class EmbedTestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // When using UIContainerView, prepare for segue will be called on load

        // un-comment this block to use SELF as the delegate
        //  for the tableView in the embedded tableViewController

        //if let vc = segue.destination as? MyStaticTableViewController {
        //  vc.tableView.delegate = self
        //}

    }

    // this will only be called if .delegate is set as shown above
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAt called in \"Parent\" for indexPath:", indexPath)
    }

}

class MyStaticTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // this will NOT be called if .delegate is set as the "parent" view controller
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAt called in \"Table View Controller\" for indexPath:", indexPath)
    }

}
```

Note the comments and commented lines of code in the `prepare` func in `EmbedTestViewController`.

If you run this ***with*** those lines commented, `didSelectRowAt` will be called in `MyStaticTableViewController` class.

If you ***un-comment*** those lines, `didSelectRowAt` will be called in `EmbedTestViewController` class.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a full example: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerTableView

Comment: didSelectRowAt is not getting called in MyStaticViewController if i exactly copy it as you said

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS - I put an example project up on GitHub at: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerTableView

Comment: I found out that i disabled selection on my tableview. The work with segue is unnesseccary as you can just use `tablview.delegate = self` in the tablviewcontroller

Comment: A `UITableViewController` already has its `tableView.delegate` set to `self`, so there is no need for that line. For future reference, try to be a bit clearer when asking questions. You asked *"how can I **respond** to cell taps in static tableview?"* ... I didn't seem to indicate that your cells weren't even being selected to begin with.